# Rename file name while removing part of file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i have a folder and it contains hundreds of text file, i want to rename it .

file names     ABCD01%%.txt or CAT9999&#.txt OR FILENAME2345&^$.txt

i want to rename file such that anything that comes between 'numbers' and '.txt' should be removed

for example

- ABCD01%%.txt becomes ABCD01.txt
- CAT9999&#.txt becomes CAT9999.txt
- FILENAME2345&^$.txt becomes FILENAME2345.txt

Code so far:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /l /a-d /b *.txt') do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" %%n in ("%%~nf") do (
        echo File: %%~nxf = value %%n

    rename %%~nxf *%%n.txt



    )
)
```

Another solution i get for linux is `rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]//g' *.txt` , i tried to port it for windows but i cant .. how can the above  command be ported to windows (batch)

Comment: what have you tired so far?

Comment: @QueenSvetlana 
FOR /R %~dp0 %%G IN ([0-9]*.) DO (
  echo %%~nG
)

Comment: @QueenSvetlana can u help

Comment: What is your plan if multiple files would become the same name? `ABCD01%%.txt` and `ABCD01-&%.txt` would both become `ABCD01.txt`.

Comment: @lit hi , in my case this case does not exist

Comment: @user143252 - Robust code must be prepared for anything. Do you just want something quick and cheap that might occasionally fail or possibly overwrite files?

Comment: @lit ok i understand but i am new this field i tried .. please share your answer

Comment: @user143252 - I do not have an answer. This is a business decision. Please think through what you would want to happen and add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicate renames and assuming that only letters and numbers make up the first part of the filename, the following code will rename the files. When you are satisfied that the renaming is being done correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.txt' |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '([A-Za-z0-9]*).*\.txt' } |
    ForEach-Object { Rename-Item $_.FullName "$($matches[1]).txt" -WhatIf }
```

If you are not running in PowerShell, put the code into a renfunc.ps1 file and invoke it from the cmd .bat script.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File 'renfunc.ps1'
```

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered a few problems with escaping characters, I had to use a slightly different method. This script should work:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set name=%%~nf
    for /f "delims=0123456789 tokens=2" %%r in ("%%~nf") do set replace=%%r
    set "replace=name:!replace:^^=!="
    for /f %%x in ("!replace!") do set replace=!%%x!
    ren "!name!.txt" "!replace!.txt"
)
```

**EDIT:** This revised script looks for the last numbers in the file name. [*Don't mind the errors, they don't have any effect on the actual renaming.*]

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set name=%%~nf
    set p=0
    for /l %%# in (2 1 32) do (
        for %%e in ("!name:~-%%#,1!") do (
            echo.%%~e|findstr /r /i "[0-9]"&&if !p!==0 set /a p=%%#-1
        )
    )
    set "new=name:~,-!p!"
    for %%e in ("!name:~-1!") do echo.%%~e|findstr /r /i "^[0-9]"&&set new=name
    for /f %%x in ("!new!") do ren "!name!.txt" "!%%~x!.txt"
)
```

**EDIT:** Revised again for the special case of "&&". Delayed expansion within a for-loop can be tedious. Now the characters won't break syntax anymore (which means the errors that were to be ignored have ceased).

Comment: Thanks for the solution but  in this case it looks like your script wont work , if filename is N6DUK01##.TXT   needed as N6DUK01.TXT       , one of the solution i found for linux is  [  rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]//g' *.txt  ]  can you make windows version above command , thanks in advance

Comment: @user143252 I have edited my script, though you're probably better off with the powershell solution posted above.

Comment: thanks second one is working fine  , when the file name is like cat01&&.txt it wont work may be coz & is treated differently

Comment: @user143252 I realise it doesn't matter anymore, but I edited my script to work with any case (hopefully).